# Amazon CloudFront origin server for dynamic images

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I need to dynamically generate images based on URL parameters e.g. width, height, fit, fill etc. So far I've been using Google App Engine's image API serving url functionality however it doesn't provide all the functionality I need.

My idea is to have AWS CloudFront serve my images from an origin server. The origin server would get the images from S3, process them using GraphicsMagick (since it's much faster than ImageMagick), then serve them.

I'm not so sure about what server infrastructure I should use since my server will do one thing only: serve images. Using a normal stack seems too much and I'm really concerned about speed. I was thinking about lighttpd + a WSGI application in python since I come from a Django background.

Would it be better to use python's own web server BaseHTTPServer instead of lighttpd? Any idea of a server stack would be great or even another Image Processing System.

Comment: you might want to look into Blitline http://www.blitline.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this post?

http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/dynamic-content/

Comment: This is what I was going to use. What I was asking about is what's an optimal origin server stack.

Comment: I have experience using both IIS and S3. I had no problem with IIS, the major downside IMHO is that you have to take care of your server load. With S3, fire and forget, just put your photos in S3 and setup your cloud front to use your S3 bucket as origin.